# how to tranfrom python3 program into exe file totally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I have heard py2exe,but it doesn't support python3 now.So I found cxfreeze,but there is an problem that the extension lib are in a zip file,but one extension must use a txt file.The extension would figure out the txt file address,which in the zip file.Windows throw out an error of 'FileNotFoundError'.The problem nearly drive me mad.It can't open file that compressed in zip.I am begging for your help...

Comment: You'll have to modify the bit of code that loads the text file to look somewhere else for it, or load it from the zip file. See [Using data files](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) in the FAQ.

Comment: Thank you, I modify the source code that loads the file,and it works.Actually I had read the official document of cxfreeze a little bit but lose the FAQ.Thank you very much @ThomasK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

Programs that load data files may need to be modified a bit if they're looking for the data files adjacent to Python modules, because cx_Freeze puts the Python modules into a zip file. Depending on your use case, you could load the data from the zip file (using the zipfile module), or load it from a regular file alongside the exe. The [cx_Freeze FAQ](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files) has an example of how to do the latter.

Another option, especially for small pieces of data, is to embed it in Python code so it's in a frozen module. Qt's resource system works like this.